Laravel: Array result is "true" instead object
I'm building a diet plan with Laravel 8.
Database looks like this:



Recipes
Category
Calories




Eggs
breakfast
180


Yogourt
breakfast
50


Apple pie
snacks
289


Banana pie
snacks
386


Tomato Pasta
lunch-dinner
712


Chicken Salad
lunch-dinner
956


Vegetables soup
lunch-dinner
410


Fish with potatoes
lunch-dinner
652



I'd like to get the day's meals according to average daily calories.
For example, if my daily calories is 1500kcal, I want to get 4 recipes (breakfast/lunch/dinner/snacks) for the day whose total calories are between 1300-1500 calories.
I use the same category for lunch and dinner but I need 2 results from this category.
I built some functions to do this:
use App\Models\Recipe;

// Function to generate combinations of recipes
function generateCombinations($items, $n, $start = 0, $result = [], &$results = []) {
    if ($n === 0) {
        $results[] = $result;
        return;
    }

    for ($i = $start; $i < count($items); $i++) {
        $result[] = $items[$i];
        generateCombinations($items, $n - 1, $i + 1, $result, $results);
        array_pop($result);
    }
}

// Function to filter combinations by total calories
function filterCombinationsByCalories($combinations, $dailyCalories) {
    return array_filter($combinations, function($combination) use ($dailyCalories) {
        $totalCalories = array_sum(array_column($combination, 'calories'));
        return $totalCalories >= $dailyCaloriesMin && $totalCalories <= $dailyCalories;
    });
}

// Function to get daily meal plan
function getDailyMealPlan($dailyCalories) {
    $mealCategories = ['breakfast','lunch-dinner', 'snacks'];
    $mealPlan = [];

    foreach ($mealCategories as $category) {
        $recipes = Recipe::where('category', $category)->get()->toArray();

        // Generate combinations of recipes for this meal category
        $combinations = [];
        generateCombinations($recipes, 1, 0, [], $combinations);

        // Filter combinations by total calories
        $filteredCombinations = filterCombinationsByCalories($combinations, $dailyCalories);

        // If there are no valid combinations, choose a single recipe with the highest calories
        if (empty($filteredCombinations)) {
            $selectedRecipe = Recipe::where('category', $category)->orderBy('calories', 'desc')->first();
            $mealPlan[$category] = $selectedRecipe;
        } else {
            // Randomly select a combination from the filtered combinations
            $selectedCombination = $filteredCombinations[array_rand($filteredCombinations)];
            $mealPlan[$category] = $selectedCombination;
        }
    }

    return $mealPlan;
}

// Example usage
$dailyCalories = 1500;
$dailyCaloriesMin = 1300;
$mealPlan = getDailyMealPlan($dailyCalories);
print_r($mealPlan);

But I got a "true" instead an object.
It works if I remove the minimum calories but the total number of calories is often less than 1300:
// Function to filter combinations by total calories
function filterCombinationsByCalories($combinations, $dailyCalories) {
    return array_filter($combinations, function($combination) use ($dailyCalories) {
        $totalCalories = array_sum(array_column($combination, 'calories'));
        return $totalCalories <= $dailyCalories;
    });
}

Any solution?

What exactly is returning true?
